# Using <include> in android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout not displaying correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-gridlayout, android-include

I'm trying to use `<include>` to include `ImageButton`s inside a `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`. The problem is, if I don't specify all the attributes explicitly on my `<include>` elements, they don't display properly. In other words, the include is pointless since I have to redeclare all the attributes on every `<include>` element.

**dialpad_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

**dialpad_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dialpad_grid_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowCount="1">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/dialpad_view_btn1"
        android:src="@drawable/dialpad_1"
        layout="@layout/dialpad_button" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/dialpad_view_btn2"
        android:src="@drawable/dialpad_2"
        layout="@layout/dialpad_button" />


</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

If I declare all the attributes directly on the `<include>`s, here's what it looks like in XML:

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/dialpad_button"
        android:id="@+id/dialpad_view_btn1"
        android:src="@drawable/dialpad_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

As you can see in the comparison image below, the buttons now scale properly but the images are nowhere to be seen.

And if I change the `<include>`s to `ImageButton`, things work as expected.

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dialpad_view_btn1"
        android:src="@drawable/dialpad_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

[image: Comparison of different XML-layouts]

Is there a workaround to this?

Since I'm going to have 12 near-identical buttons in my dialpad, I'd really like to clean the XML up by including a "template" and only modifying the necessary attributes for each button (i.e. `src` and `id`).

**EDIT**

Trying to use styles, as suggested in one answer, did not work. None of the views that I applied the styles to get displayed. What's even more strange, even if I just apply the style to one of the views in the `GridLayout`, only the last view gets displayed (I've shortened down the sample code here to only two views for readability, in reality I have twelve).

Here's the style I tried using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <style name="dialPadButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
        <item name="grid:layout_columnWeight">1</item>
        <item name="grid:layout_rowWeight">1</item>
        <item name="grid:layout_gravity">fill</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a style to declare the common attributes and then set it for every button.

```
<style name="dialPadButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_rowWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:src">@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera</item>
</style>
```

I also added: columnCount to 3 and rowCount to 4 for GridLayout and added 12 ImageButtons with that style. The final result is this:
[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work. None of the views that I apply the styles to are displayed. Even stranger is that even if I apply the style to only one of the views, only the last view in the GridLayout is displayed!

Comment: Can you post the style, please?

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it to see if it's ok now :D

Comment: It works with `GridLayout`, but not `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`. Unfortunately,  `GridLayout` is not available before API 21, and I'm targeting API 14 and up.

Comment: If you have only 12 button, why don't you use some nested linear layouts? Isn't that OK?

Comment: Yes I could do that, just wanted to know why it doesn't work with the support `GridLayout` and what can be done about it. It will hopefully help people looking for an answer to this in the future as well, because I couldn't find any SO threads about this specific issue.